# How to run multiple command line in Azure Pool start task

Tags: azure, command-line, azure-batch

I'm trying to run this command line in Azure Batch node start up task

```
sudo wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u161-b12/2f38c3b165be4555a1fa6e98c45e0808/jdk-8u161-linux-x64.rpm" && sudo yum localinstall jdk-8u161-linux-x64.rpm -y
```

However, It always failed with this kind of error in the log file

```
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
```

Looks like it doesnt understand the && operator. I've remotely logged in the VM via ssh and try the command and it worked. Please advice if you've got any experience with this. Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should start the command with `/bin/bash -c` and then put the command in double quotes, escaping the inner double quotes.

So something like this should work:
`/bin/bash -c "sudo wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header \"Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie\" \"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u161-b12/2f38c3b165be4555a1fa6e98c45e0808/jdk-8u161-linux-x64.rpm\" && sudo yum localinstall jdk-8u161-linux-x64.rpm -y"`

Comment: Additionally, it's recommended to use the appropriate [User Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-user-accounts) with elevation rather than explicit `sudo`.

Comment: No problem - if it worked could you please mark it as the correct answer? Thanks

Comment: How can we run multiple commands, one runs on cmd and other on @powershell on Windows server ?